# IE7 compatible CSS framework

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-frameworks

Are there any css frameworks, that fully support IE7? Something like Twitter Bootstrap, but when I use it in IE7, I have no rounded corners, and the tabs are broken. Popover plugin fails, so IE shows "This script is executing too long, would you stop it?"

Comment: Initializr might be worth a look: http://www.initializr.com/

Comment: But it also uses Bootstrap, which does not work in IE7.

Comment: I think it also uses Modernizr and Boilerplate to allow IE compatibility. Sorry if it's no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inuit.css](http://inuitcss.com/) supports IE7 (there's even an option that supplies IE6 support, though I hope no one will ever use that).

And inuit.css just happens to be the best framework out there anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it is not a UI CSS framework.

Comment: Ok, seems I misunderstood the question somewhat. It's generally viewed as good practice to use "progressive enhancement", meaning you should seriously consider if you need to have rounded corners etc for ie7 users, considering it will come at a considerable cost for people using modern browsers. You would have to use images to achieve the same look in IE7. Same applies to shadows and a bunch of other things. Generally I've found Bootstrap to look ok in IE7 (which is listed as a supported browser).